# How to add column using alter in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql

How to add the column using alter by inputting the values on it?
As the example, I want to add *tempID*'s column which has value "3" on every row

Maybe it's something like this

```
ALTER TABLE NAMEYOURTABLE
   ADD COLUMN last_update TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

but the code above is only for the timestamp, not for integer values. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You should check out this https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/alter-table.html

For your case it would be something like

```
ALTER TABLE NAMEYOURTABLE ADD COLUMN tempID int NULL DEFAULT 3;
```

Answer (score 2):

Along with Jovana's answer, you can specify after which column you need the new column with `AFTER` .

```
ALTER TABLE NAMEYOURTABLE ADD tempID int NULL DEFAULT 3 
AFTER YOUREXISTINGCOLUMNNAME;
```

Answer (score -1):

Refer : https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_alter.asp

Example to add a column:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name
ADD column_name datatype;
```