# How can I insert a new column in my table using php and mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I'm trying to add the column "test" in my table "reservation"
but it doesn't work

do you have an idea why?

```
$create = $bdd->prepare('ALTER TABLE reservation ADD test INT NULL');
```

**Database:**

[image]

Comment: your syntax is invalid. Look here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44067633/how-to-add-column-using-alter-in-mysql.  Also recommended : read the manual.  Also : check your status after any api call (prepare). Also recommended : kick the tires in a terminal before wasting your time in code.

Comment: And "it doesn't work" should be replaced with the actual error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mysql syntax seems correct, but did you try querying it instead of creating a prepared statement?

(Also, please elaborate by posting error messages, more code, context of the problem, etc.)

From what I see, you're not executing the statement.

```
$create = $bdd->prepare('ALTER TABLE reservation ADD test INT NULL');
$create->execute();
```

If you're not going to insert user created data, you can also try querying the database instead:

```
$create = $bdd->query('ALTER TABLE reservation ADD test INT NULL');
```

Not sure if this third one is required, but I usually add "COLUMN" to the query. It may depend on what DB engine you're using (Don't quote me on that)

```
ALTER TABLE reservation ADD COLUMN test INT NULL
```

Good luck!