# How can I add a column with int datatype to a table in SQL using the ALTER command?

Tags: mysql, sql, alter-table

I tried the code given in a similar question but I'm getting the following error:

```
ALTER TABLE Employees ADD Salary, int;
```

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ' int' at line 1

I'm new to MySQL and programming in general, please do tell me if the code is incorrect or if there are any rules to be followed when writing the code.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add column using alter in mysql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44067633/how-to-add-column-using-alter-in-mysql)

Comment: @nopassport1 It is best to provide links to primary sources (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/)

Comment: You have an inappropriate comma.

Answer (score 1):

The syntax is ALTER TABLE ADD **COLUMN**:

```
ALTER TABLE Employees ADD COLUMN Salary int;
```